# Ultrawingrid scrolling to bottom

Tags: c#, infragistics

Currently my test-ultrawingrid is populated with around 1000 rows. When I scroll all the way to the bottom (using the vertical scrollbar), the ultrawingrid stops when the last row reaches the top of the grid, not the bottom.
In other words - when I scroll down as far as I can, the last row appears right at the very top of the grid, leaving the rest of the grid blank.

How can I set the grid to stop scrolling-down once the final row enters the bottom of the grid (not reaches the top)?

(I hope this is a clear enough question - as it was a little hard to articulate!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the `ScrollBounds` property on the grid's DisplayLayout.

By default, this is set to `ScrollToLastItem`, you desire `ScrollToFill`.